# About junit test suite

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choose order to execute JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669414/choose-order-to-execute-junit-tests)

I am writing a JUnit test. My classes cannot be tested independently, one test depends on another one sequentially.
May I ask: If I have setUp() in the suite class, can I run test cases sequentially and let them share the same context?

Thank you and have a great day. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at answers in similar posts [specifying-order-of-execution-in-junit-test-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528581/specifying-order-of-execution-in-junit-test-case/9529014#9529014) and [choose-order-to-execute-junit-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669414/choose-order-to-execute-junit-tests).

I think instead of relying on the sequential execution, it is better to have `SetUp` (method annotated with `@Before`) and `TearDown`(method annotated with `@After`) methods.